# How can I mock a function results in spec.

Tags: rspec

I have a method that fetching a file from s3

```
def self.fetch_file(file_name)
  s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new
  s3.get_object(bucket:'myBucket', key: file_name)
end
```

then I have a method that calls the fetch_file method

```
def self.import_file(file_name)
    response = fetch_file(file_name)
    .. do some staff
```

I want to test the import_file method, 
how can I mock the results from fetch_file ?

Comment: `expect(ClassName).to receive(:fetch_file).and_return(your_mock)` where ClassName is the class that has the `import_file` method and `your_mock` is your double that you want to stub.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the allow...to receive... and return syntax. Example in this case.

```
allow(ClassName).to receive(:fetch_file).and_return("filename")
```